# MediaPlayer setPlaybackParams crash

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

When I try changing the playback params of a MediaPlayer my app crashes.
I am not sure why this is happening.

Here is the code I am using to change the playback speed.

```
PlaybackParams params = new PlaybackParams().allowDefaults();
params.setSpeed(mPlaybackRate.getValue());
mMediaPlayer.setPlaybackParams(params);
```

In this case mPlaybackRate.getValue() returns 1.25f

This is the crash log:

```
08-02 21:09:35.184 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                     Process: com.hackmodford.bigfinish, PID: 30986
                                     java.lang.IllegalStateException
                                         at android.media.MediaPlayer.setPlaybackParams(Native Method)
                                         at com.hackmodford.bigfinish.mediaPlayerService.MediaPlayerService.incrementPlaybackRate(MediaPlayerService.java:543)
                                         at com.hackmodford.bigfinish.mediaPlayerService.MediaPlayerService.access$1000(MediaPlayerService.java:47)
                                         at com.hackmodford.bigfinish.mediaPlayerService.MediaPlayerService$3.onCustomAction(MediaPlayerService.java:336)
                                         at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat$Callback$StubApi21.onCustomAction(MediaSessionCompat.java:832)
                                         at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompatApi21$CallbackProxy.onCustomAction(MediaSessionCompatApi21.java:231)
                                         at android.media.session.MediaSession$CallbackMessageHandler.handleMessage(MediaSession.java:1246)
                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: is the media playing when you call that method?

Comment: @muratgu yes it is.

Comment: well maybe that's the cause.

Comment: I have tried calling pause just before making the change and it didn't make a difference. The documentation also says that the only invalid states to call this is idle or stopped. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: For what it's worth I see this on phones (nexus 5 and the Priv) but not on tablets (nexus 9 and nexus 7) all updated the the latest version (6.0.1, updated Aug 5, 2016)

Comment: I've got the same problem when setting playback speed to 2 on my Nexus 9, after investigating and no clue to the problem, I simply tried and catched the exception and show a toast about this speed isn't supported. But strangely now with the same video I cannot even repeat the problem again.

Answer (score 3):

you have to ensure your mediaPlayer is prepared!
so you can try set a listener like this:

```
mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener(){
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer var1) {
               PlaybackParams params = mMediaPlayer.getPlaybackParams();
               params.setSpeed(3.0f);
               mMediaPlayer.setPlaybackParams(params); 
             }
        });
```

it works for me.

Answer (score -3):

```
mPlayer.getPlaybackParams().setSpeed(1.5f);
```

Comment: can you add more detail? one single line of code doesn't help futur readers

Comment: Usually it is a good idea to add an explanation to your post that talks about how the code works. This allows new developers to understand what the code does.